# serving static files to angular using flask

Tags: angular, flask

I'm a beginner to angular and flask . I'm working on a small project for which frontend is angular which gets the necessary data from a flask API. I can serve the backend data to angular application using proxy and the data retrival is fine. But when it comes into images I couldn't make it. I have properly configured my images inside '/static' folder on flask which run on localhost:5000. I'm able to retrieve the images with the URL 'http://localhost:5000/static/image/image_1.jpg'.

My angular app run on  localhost:4200 which uses the following proxy configuration
proxy.config.json

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000",
      "secure": false
    },
    "/static": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000",
        "secure": false
    }
    
}
```

Retrieval of data using 'http://localhost:4200/api/food' is fine but for images 'http://localhost:4200/static/images/image_1.jpg' is not working.

Hoping for a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The images you use in angular should be stored in assets directory of your angular app. But if these images are uploaded by user, you may want to setup a file server and return image path with your api and use that path in angular.

Comment: I've seen blog on google about serving static using express server, I wanted to do the using flask, is that not possible??